# js reduce of an array with only empty values

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this iterate?

```
(Array(5)).reduce(function(cur,prv,n,a){alert(n)},'');
```

I never reached the function body, seemingly ignoring all of the empty values, which is not what I want it to do.

Comment: This throws an error: `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`

Comment: It's not an empty array, all values in it are of type `undefined`

Comment: Try `Array.apply(0, Array(5)).reduce`

Comment: it looks like you're missing closing parens, is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, the implementation of reduce causes this to throw a TypeError because the calling array has no initial values. To initialize an array with initial values of undefined and successfully invoke the function, try something like this:

```
Array.apply(undefined, Array(5)).reduce(function(cur,prv,n,a){alert(n)},'');
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand `Array(5)` returns an instance of `Array Object` with a property `length` (value 5), but without values. One way to be able to use `reduce` (or other array methods like `map`) here is:

```
String(Array(5)).split(',').reduce(function (cur, prv, n, a) { /* ... */ })
```

An alternative could be:

```
Array.apply(null,{length: 5}).map( [callback] );
// or
Array.apply(null,Array(5)).map( [callback] );
```

But that *will* encounter a maximum call stack error at some point. The string/split method keeps working (albeit a bit slower) for large arrays. Using node.js on my (not so fast) computer mapping `Array(1000000)` with the string/split-method lasts 0.47 seconds, the array.apply method for the same crashes with a `RangeError` (*Maximum call stack size exceeded*).

You can also write a 'static' Array method to create an `Array` with n values and all usable/applicable `Array` methods in place:

```
Array.create = function (n, mapCB, method, initial) {
  method = method in [] ? method : 'map';
  var nwArr = ( function(nn){ while (nn--) this.push(undefined); return this; } )
                .call([], n);
  return mapCB ? nwArr[method](mapCB, initial) : nwArr;
};
// usages
Array.create(5, [callback], 'reduce', '');
Array.create(5).reduce( [callback], '');
Array.create(5).map( [callback] ).reduce( [callback] );
// etc.
```

Comment: Good solution, but conversion to string and then splitting is quite slow for larger array's. I like my code lean, so I hope someone knows a solution I can use the plain array with reduce, otherwise I'll use a for loop